# How to validate a character where it must exist in specific conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this regex expression:

```
(([aA-zZ]{2}[0-9]{5})(\w{2})?((XX)|(xx))?(\;)?)*
```

Basically it validates positive these examples:

```
zz01104;ZZ02045PA;
zz00110;AH12204
AG01104xx
EV99337xx;
```

It works as intended, the problem is this one:

```
zz00110AH12204;
```

There should be a `;` between these two, but I don't know how can you control this directly with the regex expression.

Comment: "There should be" How can you say there should be ? Why can't that be valid ? What is the condition for it to be valid or not ?

Comment: Yes ^ can you please state what the scenario you want to validate is?
e.g a `String` of `Numbers`, `Letters` & `[specific] Special Characters` starting with `two` `Letters` followed by between `5-7 Numbers`... etc

Comment: Try [`^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}(?:\w{2})?(?:XX|xx)?(?:;[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}(?:\w{2})?(?:XX|xx)?)*;?$`](https://regex101.com/r/sxyiJh/1)

Comment: What i mean is that i want to validate that as a negative, so, if you put two sequences without the ; it should return as false.

Comment: @Maxrunner: are `ZZ02045PAXX` or `ZZ02045xX` or `ZZ0204567` or `ZZ02045__` valid?

Comment: The solution from Wiktor was sucessful

Comment: @Maxrunner: It does not exempt you from answering the questions you were asked and from giving the necessary details to make your request understandable.

Comment: Well that user completely understood what i meant. But yes next time i will elaborate better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}(?:\w{2})?(?:XX|xx)?(?:;[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}(?:\w{2})?(?:XX|xx)?)*;?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sxyiJh/1).

In JS, you may build the pattern dynamically to avoid writing the regex parts twice:

```js
var rxPart = "[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}(?:\\w{2})?(?:XX|xx)?";
var rx = new RegExp("^" + rxPart + "(?:;" + rxPart + ")*;?$");
var strs = [ 'zz01104;ZZ02045PA', 'zz00110;AH12204', 'AG01104xx', 'EV99337xx', 'zz00110AH12204'];
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

You can see that the pattern structure is

- `^` - start of the string
- `rxPart` - your single item pattern
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `;` - a semi-colon
  - *rxPart* - your single item pattern
- `)*` - any 0 or more occurrences of the pattern sequence in the group
- `;?` - an optional `;`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution :)